# How to change a buttons name through string in Swift?

Tags: swift, function

For my first app I am making a game in which the player can change the difficulty. When he choose a difficulty, some values must be changed.

One of this values is "maxDynamites" and I am using 2 difficulties, easy and normal. On easy, the value is 3 and on normal mode the value is 1.

Now, I have declared it as followed:

```
func setDifficulty()
{
    if Difficulty == 0
    {
        maxDynamites = dif0MaxDynamites
        else if Difficulty == 1
        {
            maxDynamites = dif1MaxDynamites
        }
    }
}
```

This will do the trick, but I am planning for a lot more variables to use and more difficulties. Is there a way I can remove the dif0MaxDynamites and change it to something that will automatically change the "0" to a "1" if the difficulty is set to normal? I don't think using if's all the time is correct, and in this way I must copy paste my code for the amount of difficulties... Any help is welcome.

Comment: Btw, what has the title of this question to do with the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Containing your settings in a `struct` might help;

```
struct DifficultySettings {
    static let easyModeSettings = DifficultySettings(maxDynamites: 3, maxHealth: 100, maxShields: 5)
    static let normalModeSettings = DifficultySettings(maxDynamites: 1, maxHealth: 80, maxShields: 2)
    static let hardModeSettings = DifficultySettings(maxDynamites: 1, maxHealth: 40, maxShields: 1)

    let maxDynamites: Int
    let maxHealth: Int
    let maxShields: Int
}
```

The `static` variables can contain all the different parameters. Easy to modify etc.

```
func setDifficulty(mode: DifficultySettings) {
    // Setup the game based on settings
    print("Max dynamites: \(mode.maxDynamites)")
    print("Max health: \(mode.maxHealth)")
    print("Max shields: \(mode.maxShields)")
}
```

You can hook up your buttons to something like:

```
func setDifficultyToEasy() {
    setDifficulty(.easyModeSettings)
}

func setDifficultyToNormal() {
    setDifficulty(.normalModeSettings)
}

func setDifficultyToHard() {
    setDifficulty(.hardModeSettings)
}
```

With a solution like this, it's easy to add both more difficulties and game parameters.

You could pass a `DifficultySetting` to your game logic, and your game logic can use the values contained within it.

Comment: Yes! Everything I needed to know :)